# How to ssh at computer inside home network

Tags: ssh, openssh, dropbear

I am running a home network with a ddwrt installed router.
I can ssh into the router from homenetwork, i can ssh in the pc from inside the homenetwork, i can ssh into the router from outside the home network ( static public ip).
Now i want to ssh in my pc from outside the home network, as far as i have understood, to do that i need to create a ssh tunnel. I am using the following command :

```
ssh -L bbbb:hoomepcip:22 root:externalip
```

after doing this i open another terminal and i

```
ssh homepcusername@externalip -p bbbb
```

but it does not work, what am i doing wrong

Isn't the first command supposed to do a port forward in the router so everything i send to it's external ip on bbbb port goes to 22 of my home pc?

for now i have made a permanent port forward on the router gui, but i would like to not use that and open the port when i need to ssh.

both the router and the pc have SSH server installed, the router has dropbear the pc openssh

Comment: Not a programming question, hence off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for me.
So as i said i needed a way to ssh into my pc from outside my network through my router.
first open a terminal window and type

```
ssh -L bbbb:homepcIP:cc myrouterusername@mywanip -p aa
```

this will connect you to the router and forward port bbbb(chose a number from 1024-60000) to cc in your pc(usually 22)
type the password and leave it open

then open a new terminal window and type

```
ssh pcUSERNAME@localhost -p bbbb
```

bbbb in this case can be any port number you choose(best if above 1024, and max limit is 60000ish)

cc and bb are the port of the ssh servers (cc of my pc and bb of my router, they usually are 22 but it can change depending on conifguartion)

the key here is the "localhost" i always typed my pc ip in there but you have to type localhost and it connects to the pc correctly.

Also you have to have enabled SSH TCP Forwarding in the first server

Answer (score 0):

Instead of SSH tunneling, you might consider [tailscale](https://tailscale.com/).

See for instance "[How to secure an Ubuntu server using Tailscale and UFW](https://tailscale.com/kb/1077/secure-server-ubuntu-18-04)", which will  restrict ssh access to be only over Tailscale, and use UFW (Uncomplicated Firewall) to restrict non-Tailscale traffic to your server.
That will give you a Tailscale IP address (starting with 100.x.y.z) which can be used to SSH, while your public internet IP would not allow SSH.
You can then add [MFA (multi-factor auth)](https://tailscale.com/kb/1075/multi-factor-auth) if you want.

Other example: "[How to Setup SSH using Tailscale or Ngrok](https://medium.com/@jarifibrahim/how-to-setup-ssh-using-tailscale-or-ngrok-60482cdee983)" from [Ibrahim Jarif](https://github.com/jarifibrahim).

Comment: @MasterDingo Great! Don't forget to post an answer detailing what you figured out: that will help others (and you even can accept your own answer)

Comment: @MasterDingo If you don't post an answer and limit it to a comment like "I figured it out in the end", you will have a case of "Wisdom of the Ancients": https://xkcd.com/979/. Or "Margin": https://xkcd.com/1381/, in reference to Pierre de Fermat: https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/1381:_Margin. In short, don't leave all of us hanging!

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, i posted the answer!